# Spring Boot Configuration Class vs. Properties during Test

Tags: spring-boot, properties, spring-data-jpa, h2

I have little experience with the autoconfiguration of Spring Boot. What is the best practice in dealing with the database configuration for the production and the test.

Currently I have a configuration for the production which reads the database properties from a propertie file. What is the difference or what is the configuration for the entity manager. I do not create a bean but only specify the key value pairs in the file.

For the test, however, I have to create the beans, otherwise the message comes:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available

Currently my test class is as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:test-context.xml" })
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(connection = EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.H2)
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "de.xxx.xxx", repositoryBaseClass = 
                                                ExtendedRepositoryImpl.class)
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "de.xxx.xxx" })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "de.xxx.xxx" })
@EnableJpaAuditing
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = { "test" })
public abstract class AbstractTestCase {

protected static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(AbstractTestCase.class);
}
```

So what is the best in dealing with the configuration. In Java within the @Configuration or per propertie file? When should I use something?

**UPDATE 1:**
I added the @DataJpaTest annotation and remove the @Bean's from the @Configuration class. It still works, but what is the best practis to deal with? Is there a guide to understand the magic of the annotations?

Comment: The documentation can help you understand the magic of the annotations https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jpa-test specifically https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/test-auto-configuration.html

Comment: Thanks, but i almost read this. My problem is, to unterstand what is the best practice. Property and Annotation or Config class. I also had a problem with combining DataJpaTest and SpringBootTest. The best case is, having a H2TestConfig class and the right configuration. There are many posts on google dealing with different configuration. Now i am a little bit confused.

Comment: SpringBootTest = full stack, DataJpaTest = only persistence, WebMvcTest = web layer. So it doesn't make sense to combine DataJpaTest with SpringBootTest. One of the points of Spring Boot is that by using the properties, it configures the beans for you. Using a different configuration for test and prod is as easy then as creating separate `/resources/application.properties` `/test/resources/application.properties` files. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Comment: Thanks, this is what i am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is to let Spring Boot configure beans using application properties in a `application.properties` file https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html#common-application-properties.

You can use separate configuration by using separate `application.properties` files in `resources/application.properties` and `test/resources/application.properties`.